# Serialization and Deserialization in Java

Tags: java, object, serialization, deserialization

I just followed a [Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) for Serialization and I wonder why it doesn't work. I have a game Class like this:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Game implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4795536311274486893L;
    protected int SHOT_SPEED;
    protected int PLAYER_SPEED;
    Player player;
    ArrayList<SpaceObject> objects;
    int level, score;
    Dimension resolution;
    and so on...
```

And my reader methods, which should handle the Object IO looks like this:

```
public boolean saveGame(Game game) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(defaultDataName+".ser");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);

            out.writeObject(game);

            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (IOException i) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public Game loadGame() throws IOException {
        if (readRawData(defaultDataName) == "") throw new IOException("Data was deleted");
        Game game = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(defaultDataName+".ser");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

            game = (Game) in.readObject();

            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new IOException("Class not Found: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return game;
    }
```

To my mind I did everything exactly like in the tutorial, so why doesn't it works out. (it throws an ClassNotFoundError. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which class is not found? Is it a class you removed?

Comment: the Player class, so does every Class which is contained have to implement Serializable?

Comment: Every class needs to implement Serializable including any outer classes, but if you are getting `ClassNotFoundException` it means the *class could not be found*

Comment: When you catch an exception, *never* just `return false;`. Always log the cause. Otherwise you have no hope of finding out what went wrong.

Comment: yeah, I should really start doing this, it helped me really later on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every class that is contained within a Serializable marked class should be serializable. I think that's the error you get.

Comment: Not doing that won't cause `ClassNotFoundException`. @DanielSchmidt This can't be the right answer unless there is something else you aren't telling us.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the class is not in your classpath when running the second method.

- Could you post the entire exception message?
- Are you using the serialize and deserializer with the same classpath?